# Horizantal scroll right to element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to scroll to right of each element, but could not calculate right of element and scroll to it.

```js
var $scroller = $('.scroller');
    $('button').on('click', function() {
      var divIdx = $('input').val();

      var scrollTo = $('#d' + divIdx)
        .css('background', '#9f3')
        .position().left;
      console.log(scrollTo);
      $scroller
        .animate({
          'scrollLeft': scrollTo
        }, 500);
    });
```

```css
.scroller {
   width: 300px;
   height: 100px;
   overflow-x: auto;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   direction: rtl;
 }

 .container {
   position: relative;
   /*important for the .position() method */
   height: 100px;
   width: 770px;
 }

 .container div {
   height: 90px;
   width: 60px;
   float: right;
   margin: 5px;
   background: #39f;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroller">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="d1"></div>
    <div id="d2"></div>
    <div id="d3"></div>
    <div id="d4"></div>
    <div id="d5"></div>
    <div id="d6"></div>
    <div id="d7"></div>
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</div>
<button>Scroll to: </button> <input type="text" value="4" />
```

How to calculate right of element and scroll to right of element?
How to calculate right of element and scroll to right of element?
How to calculate right of element and scroll to right of element?

Comment: The desired result is not clear to me. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @KoshVery I am using RTL direction, need to set scroll right to right of element, thats all

Comment: Your snippet shows scrolling from left to right. Scrolling "to right of element" would result in the element got out of the container left border. You need that? Or what?

Comment: @KoshVery In snippet you see rtl container, scroll is in right when you run snippet, then you click on button, it scroll somewhere.. but I need to scroll to right side of element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this one.

```js
var $scroller = $('.scroller');
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var divIdx = $('input').val();
  var div = $('#d' + divIdx);

  div.css('background', '#9f3');
  var divLeft = div.offset().left;
  var divWidth = div.width();
  var scrollerWidth = $('.scroller').width();

  var scrollTo = divLeft - scrollerWidth + divWidth;

  $scroller
    .animate({
      'scrollLeft': scrollTo
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
.scroller {
   width: 300px;
   height: 100px;
   overflow-x: auto;
   overflow-y: hidden;
 }

 .container {
   position: relative;
   /*important for the .position() method */
   height: 100px;
   width: 770px;
 }

 .container div {
   height: 90px;
   width: 60px;
   float: left;
   margin: 5px;
   background: #39f;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroller">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="d1"></div>
    <div id="d2"></div>
    <div id="d3"></div>
    <div id="d4"></div>
    <div id="d5"></div>
    <div id="d6"></div>
    <div id="d7"></div>
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</div>
<button>Scroll to: </button> <input type="text" value="5" />
```

Comment: Please see my snippet in question again

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add some right margin and it's all done!

```js
var $scroller = $('.scroller');
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var divIdx = $('input').val();
  var scrollTo = $('#d' + divIdx)
    .css('background', '#9f3')
    .position().left;
  console.log(scrollTo);
  $scroller
    .animate({
      'scrollLeft': scrollTo
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
.scroller {
   width: 300px;
   height: 100px;
   overflow-x: auto;
   overflow-y: hidden;
 }

 .container {
   position: relative;
   /*important for the .position() method */
   height: 100px;
   width: 600px;
 }

 .container div {
   height: 90px;
   width: 60px;
   float: right;
   margin: 5px;
   background: #39f;
 }
 .container div:first-child {
   margin-right: 240px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroller">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="d1"></div>
    <div id="d2"></div>
    <div id="d3"></div>
    <div id="d4"></div>
    <div id="d5"></div>
    <div id="d6"></div>
    <div id="d7"></div>
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</div>
<button>Scroll to: </button> <input type="text" value="4" />
```

Comment: No no, I need to set scroll right to right of element

Comment: Please see my snippet in question again

Answer (score 0):

There are two points to consider -

1. position().left gives you the value of the distance upto left edge of element only. So to get the value upto right edge, you can take left position of the element + the width of the element. `$('#d' + divIdx).position().left + $('#d' + divIdx).width()`
2. There should be additional one item's width white space after the last item which allow the scrollbar to move upto the end of the last item.